# General query for getting data from other users

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

This is a bit of a general question.

I am creating a tournament scheduler in Excel and I was wondering if I could do something a bit more advanced than just spreadsheet sharing for teams to update their scores.

My thinking is this: Create a macro with specific username and password for each team and they can then only update their own scores, and have the opposing team be able to approve the scores to validate them. I don't think that coding this would be a problem but my issue here is that I do not know where I can upload this for everybody in the tournament can have access to it as we do not have a shared file server. How can I have the shared spreadsheet available to everybody freely?

Comment: Prepare your Excel sheet offline and share it online with Office 365 (newer office versions only) or upload the spreadhseet to Google Docs (other formula syntax needed) and grant access to different gmail accounts

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Dropbox](http://dropbox.com/) or something similar, but then you'd have the problem of more than one person accessing it simultaneously, so you'd need to coordinate somehow.

Depending on the complexity of the macro, why not use a [Google Drive Spreadsheet](https://drive.google.com/)? They've gotten a lot more advanced in recent years...

You'll need to write an **Apps Script** which will function as a macro and can also interact with other Google documents I believe. There's a good info page here: [Extend Google Docs, Sheets, and Forms with Apps Script - Drive Help](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2942256?hl=en)